# Using a Listview in chat layout

Tags: listview, nativescript

I'm using a Listview to show messages in a chat-like layout (similar to this [chat template](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/create-a-realtime-chat-interface-with-firebase-and-angular)) but having a problem with the Listview scrolling past the first row when entering a reply.

Here's my layout

```
<StackLayout>
       <ListView height="90%" class="list-group" items="{{ countries }}"
            itemTap="{{ onItemTap }}">
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">
                    <Image src="{{ imageSrc }}" class="thumb img-circle" />
                    <Label text="{{ name }}" class="list-group-item-heading"
                        verticalAlignment="center" style="width: 60%" />
                </FlexboxLayout>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <StackLayout height="10%" backgroundColor="red">
            <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="*" class="m-l-15 m-r-15 m-t-10">
                <TextField row="0" col="0" class="p-10"
                    hint="Enter your message" returnKeyType="done" />
            </GridLayout>
        </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

I've created a [playground example here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=qkGBaK) to illustrate the problem.

When you click on the textfield to add your reply, the keyboard pushes up the listview so the first rows are then no longer visible. How do I make the listview reduce in height proportionally so the first few rows are visible when entering a reply?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by keeping first few rows of ListView visible, in your Playground they are always visible. Still I would suggest using a `GridLayout` over `StackLayout` with percentage units - [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=qkGBaK&v=25)

Comment: @Manoj So when you click on the textfield to add your reply, the keyboard pushes up the listview so the first rows are no longer visible... Have tried using a GridLayout without any success.

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/867

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=qkGBaK&v=26).

You need to have dynamic height for the rows in `GridLayout` in case you want to make top section of the listview visible all the time. You can play with row height in tap and blur events of TextField.

```
<GridLayout rows="{{rowHeight}}">
```

and in your home-view-model.js

```
onFocus: function (args) {
  this.rowHeight = "100,100";
},
onBlur: function (args) {
  this.rowHeight = "500,100";
},
```

P.S You may wish to calculate Keyboard size based on different screens. Here is the same for ios

```
application.ios.addNotificationObserver(UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, function (notification) {
let hght = notification.userInfo.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey).CGRectValue.size.height;
})
```

Comment: When using the IQKeyboardManager plugin the TexField is occasionally hidden behind the keyboard which is strange.